# Quickblox IOS SDK 2.6.2 issue

Tags: ios, sdk, chat, quickblox

I have downloaded the Quickblox IOS SDK version 2.6.2.

There are some demo Project in SDK.
Like "sample-chat"

I have replaced the **"kApplicationID" "kAuthKey" "kAuthSecret" "kAccountKey"**

But when i run the project its giving the below error:-

```
[QBCore] Response error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f95b2df65f0> { URL: https://api.quickblox.com/users/by_tags.json?page=1&per_page=100&tags=dev } { status code: 404, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 1;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 20 Jan 2016 11:00:56 GMT";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2016-01-20 12:59:20 UTC";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    Status = "404 Not Found";
    "X-Rack-Cache" = miss;
    "X-Request-Id" = 8341005e68907408343438e49020e8dc;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.040315";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.quickblox.com/users/by_tags.json?page=1&per_page=100&tags=dev, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<20>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404)}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

404 error means there are no users with tag dev in your application.

Please add/register at least one user in your application.

And please update to 2.6.3 to see error details and reasons.

Comment: And why we need tag? Can you assist?

Comment: A tag is a simple mark. For example users with tag dev, users with tag production. You may leave tag empty

Answer (score 2):

Please go to Admin panel :

> Step 1 : https://admin.quickblox.com/signin.
>
> Step 2 : Login with Valid credentials.
>
> Step 3 : Go to USer >Click On Id
>
> Step 4:  Edit User tag as  == dev

Do the same for all the users.